# Cómo exportar la constante de estilos a otro archivo en React Native

Tags: react-native

Estoy comenzando en React Native y Expo, y tengo una pregunta básica, pero que no logro solucionar por mi cuenta.
Tengo una función con estilos, que he movido de mi archivo de javascript inicial (donde por cierto, me funciona) a un segundo archivo que he llamado inicio.js y la aplicación me da un error de tipo: TypeError: styles is undefined

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
```

Este es el código que tengo en el archivo inicio.js.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import colors from "../config/colors";

export default function Inicio() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.background} source={require('../assets/favicon.png')}/>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.cajas}
            placeholder="eMail"
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.cajas}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder="Contrasena"
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.boton}>
            <Text style={styles.botonTexto}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.botonTexto}>Aun no tienes una cuenta? Unete</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  )
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  background: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    width: 250,
    height: 150,
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  titulo: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: colors.rosa,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",

  },
  cajas: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingStart: 20,
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: colors.rosa,
  },
  boton: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    paddingStart: 20,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    color: colors.white,
    backgroundColor: colors.colorPrimaryDark,
  },
  botonTexto: {
    color: colors.white
  }
});
}
```

Y este es el código que tengo en el archivo principal que llama a este...

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Platform,
  ImageBackground,
  TextInput,
  Button,
} from "react-native";

import colors from "../config/colors";
import Inicio from './inicio';
import firebase from "./baseDatos";
import "firebase/auth";

    export default function App() {
    
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
        console.log(user)
      });
      return (
        <Inicio />
      )
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que `styles` está enseguida después del `return`. Por ende nunca va a evaluarse. Por eso termina teniendo un valor `undefined`.

Para resolverlo, mueve a `styles` fuera del componente `Inicio`:

```
import colors from "../config/colors";

export default function Inicio() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.background} source={require('../assets/favicon.png')}/>
        <View>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.cajas}
            placeholder="eMail"
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.cajas}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder="Contrasena"
          />
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.boton}>
            <Text style={styles.botonTexto}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={styles.botonTexto}>Aun no tienes una cuenta? Unete</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  // Mas estilos..
});
```

Ahora debería de funcionar como es esperado.